# How to handle Call<Object> Response as String?

Tags: java, android, json, api

Im in a confusing spot right now. My API returns a Token for Login when posting a new User with UserData. How do I get the response.body() as a String to save it?

It only returns a Post object what I don't actually want. I only use it to create the Post.

```
 private void createPost(User user) {

        Post post = new Post(user.getName(), user.getGender(), user.getBirthyear(), user.getHeight(),user.getWeight());
        Call<Post> call = jsonmongo.createPost(post);
        // To execute it asynchron
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("RESPONSECODE", ""+ response.code());
                    return;
                }                    
                Log.e("RESPONSECODE", ""+ response.code());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("RESPONSECODE", ""+ t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Get Response.Body and save it to the Database via SQL Adapter ( `adapter.addToken(response.body())` )

`response.body().toString` only returns Object reference ( `com.example.Resources.Post@4c8352` )

`String S = new Gson().toJson(response.body())`
`Log.e("JSON", S)`

Returns this:

`E/JSON: {"age":0,"gender":0,"height":0,"weight":0}`

Wanted output:
`E/JSON: {"token":aslfjkhr9RRRRf283FGr3489pjfGGG34HH89fj}`

Comment: The .toString() does not work for you in this case?

Comment: .toString only returns Object reference ( com.example.Resources.Post@4c8352 )

Comment: You're correct, sorry about it. I use the Gson library in that case, try: new Gson().toJson(your object);

Comment: Problem is, that my Post object has different Variables than my Json that gets returned. e.g. the variable gets lost in the process.

Comment: I provide "name, gender ...." and in return I get "token". My Post object does not contain a token. Do I need to add one, or can I somehow retain the body in another way?

Comment: In that case, you're going to set only the response values... I think I saw your point, but not tottaly sure. Let's wait for someone else to help us here! I'll think in meanwhile

Comment: you considered overriding `toString()` in the model class ?

Comment: How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

let me try... you can use Gson library to create a String json object from the response.

Try it:

```
new Gson().toJson(response);
```

Comment: Not working. Returns empty Json output:  E/JSON: {"age":0,"gender":0,"height":0,"weight":0}